# How to issue "ctrl+c" to tell a command in a just recipe to stop without killing just itself

Tags: just

I'm using a `justfile` to start a backend through docker-compose before `npm run dev`.

I would like just to run `docker compose stop backend` after I stop `npm run dev` through ctrl+c but my attempt doesn't seem to work:

```
webdev: (up-latest "backend" "-d") && (compose-stop "backend")
    cd website && npm run dev

up-latest target='' daemon='':
    docker compose up {{target}} {{daemon}}

compose-stop target='':
    docker compose stop {{target}}
```

When I run `just webdev`, everything works as expected. But when I hit `ctrl+c` just exits without running `compose-stop`.

If I understand it correctly, that's because `ctrl+c` is caught by `just` and shuts it down entirely rather than forwarding the `ctrl+c` to `npm run dev`.

So my question is: how can I send a kill signal to a recipe rather than just?

Comment: I don't know about the software you're using, but in Linux, control-c sends a SIGINT signal to a process ID. If you can get the PID of the process, maybe you can do it that way.

Comment: @JohnBayko I'm on macOS. You're right, I need to find a way to stop the npm process directly. I was wondering whether there's a built-in way to stop a recipe while keeping just running to clean up. But I guess there just isn't.